# How to detect where I was clicked before click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, editor

I have been facing a problem in my project.
Here in my project I want the position where mouse was clicked after I clicked on facebook upload button.

For example

[image: Problem Image]

Here In the image say I was clicked `Hello` text I want the position of `Hello` Text after I click on the facebook upload button and add image after the text. Similarly as the `Hello Test` case. This is where I have been trying

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Medium Editor</h1>

            <form action="{{ route('editor') }}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="editable">
                    <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="description_en" id="description_en" ></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
            <button id="facebookUpload">Facebook Upload</button>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script>


            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#facebookUpload").focusin(function(e){
                    var posX = jQuery(this).prev().focusout().position().left;
                    var posY = jQuery(this).prev().focusout().position().top;


                    jQuery('.medium-editor-element').append('<img id="theImg" src="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/jHNwCAMlTzujKkeLIyrq" style="width:100px;height:100px;left:'+ (e.pageY - posY) + ';top:'+ (e.pageX - posX) +'" />')

                    console.log((e.pageX - posX) + ' , ' + (e.pageY - posY));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this is not working. It is added image at the bottom in all case.

Here is the Example

[image: After Add Image]

I didnot find a solution for this. Plz help me. Thank You.

Comment: you can use  **javascript sessionStorage** Property. and set unique session storage when you click on your items after that get value for session storage when you hover on facebook button ... may be this would help u..

Comment: There is 2 problems with your question: **1)** You can't add an image in a `<textarea>`. But in a `<div contentEditable>`, yes. **2)** You won't be able to append anything based on x/y click coordinates. You need to target an element to append something before, after or inside.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes I want to target the <p></p> tag which is selected before I click the facebook button and add image after it. Thats what I needed. but donot know how to do it.

Comment: Okay... And another thing, are you using the [Medium Editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) plugin? *(That would explain the textarea confusion)*.

Comment: Yes I am using Medium Editor plugin. But For image I did not using medium editor. This is my Custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, please mention all relevant details about your question. Using a plugin which replaces a `<textarea>` by a `<div contentEditable>` is quite important.

There was 2 problems with your attempt:

1. You can't add an image in a `<textarea>`. But in a `<div contentEditable>`, yes.
2. You won't be able to append anything based on x/y click coordinates. You need to target an element to append something before, after or inside.

So here is a solution, using the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), to store the clicked element.

You have to check if that target is a `<p>`. Because if it's a `<div>`, it may be the editor's div... And that would be annoying to append an image after it.

So if it's not the case, keep that element in memory using a variable.

Then on the FB button click, you can append the image.

```js
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable textarea');

var clickedElement;

$(".medium-editor-element").on("click",function(e){
  
  // Making sure the click did not occured on the editor itself.
  if(e.target.tagName == "DIV" && $(e.target).hasClass("medium-editor-element")){
    return;
  }
  
  // Keep that clicked element in memory...
  clickedElement = $(e.target);
  
});

$("#facebookUpload").on("click",function(){
  if(typeof(clickedElement) != "undefined"){
    // Append an image after the last clicked element, if any.
    clickedElement.after("<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/80x80?text=IMG'>");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/medium-editor/5.23.3/css/medium-editor.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/medium-editor/5.23.3/css/themes/beagle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/medium-editor/5.23.3/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <h1>Medium Editor</h1>

  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="editable">
      <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="description_en" id="description_en" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <button id="facebookUpload">Facebook Upload</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I had added your code. also I added `<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">` but nothing happend. Image is not added.

Comment: No. Keep on with the `<textarea>` in your HTML markup... That's the plugin's job to replace it by a `<div contentEditable>`

Comment: Tried with your full code and also replace image source as mine. `clickedElement.after("<img src='https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/jHNwCAMlTzujKkeLIyrq'>");` but nothing happend. Image is not added. Its not showing any error but not working

Comment: I can't know what's wrong then. Look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for errors.

Comment: there is no error in the console but image is not added. Also I added alert in `if(typeof(clickedElement) != "undefined"){`the alert is not showing. It get the `clickedElement` undefined. thats why id did not show  the image

Comment: Well... You have to type something in the editor... and click on a word...

Comment: Thanks for your help. You saved my day